# How to run a script shell in django

Tags: django, shell

I am developing a web app using django. I've a script shell that runs python codes  for image processing. I want to execute this script shell using my web app so that users can apply image processing just by using a button in the web interface. 
(for the moment i'm working localy , the django web app and the script shell are in the same folder).
I don't know how to do it. can you help me ?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python standard library has the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html) module which can be used just for that. For instance, given `./script.sh` is your shell script a call to [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) will do the work:

```
    >>> import subprocess
    >>> # From your working directory:
    >>> subprocess.call(["./script.sh"])
```